# Import data from CSV File on different PCs

Tags: excel, vba

Importing data from CSV files is an issue for me because of the different settings on PCs. I have the following code that works on my PC well, as the CSV file reads as only one column separated by semi-colon `;` when opened by excel application
Here's the working code for me

```
Dim a, x, wb As Workbook, myPath As String, fn As String, i As Long, k As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wsMain.Cells.ClearContents
    wsMain.Range("A1").Resize(, 4).Value = Array("UNID File", "UNID", "All(MByte)", "A4")
    myPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\MyFiles\"
    fn = Dir(myPath & "*.csv")
    Do While fn <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & fn, Local:=True)
        a = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A6:A" & wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value
        wb.Close False
        Exit Do
        fn = Dir
    Loop
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a), 1 To 2)
    For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
        x = Split(a(i, 1), ";")
        If x(0) = "TEC" Then
            k = k + 1
            b(k, 1) = RemoveLeadingZeros(Split(x(1))(0))
            b(k, 2) = x(5)
        End If
    Next i
    If k > 0 Then
        wsMain.Range("B2").Resize(k, UBound(b, 2)).Value = b
    End If
```

When I sent the file with the code to someone, he has different settings, the CSV file reads as separated columns in excel not in one column as on my side. So the code didn't work properly. How can I make the code flexible to work on both PCs with these two different settings?

Posted here too with an example of the CSV file
https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1377474-import-data-from-csv-file-on-different-pcs.html

Comment: You can try to specify the delimiter in the _workbooks.open_ method (`Delimiter:=";"`)

Comment: Thanks a lot but it doesn't make difference.

Comment: have you tested `False` instead of Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & fn, Local:=`True`)

Comment: Yes, I tried but it is read as one column and I want to display as multiple columns in excel application on both pcs.

Comment: After opening the file, check to see if the worksheet contains data in only ColA, or in multiple columns, then process that sheet accordingly.  Or open the file as a text file and split each line using code similar to that you're already using.